# Use same div to toggle different parts of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Hello I have the following code:

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".clickMe").click(function() {
  $(".textBox").toggle();
 });
});
```

Html code printed with a for loop:

```
<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled</div>

<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>

<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled 3</div>
```

I would like to be able:

1. When the page loads I want the  to be hidden and toggle on click.
2. Using the same ids for `<a class="clickMe">` and `<div class="textBox">` to be able to toggle or hide the correct/equivalent `<div>` element.

jsFiddle code:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/A7Sm4/3/
```

Thanks

- Edit 1: Class instead of Id
- Edit 2: Fixed jsfiddle link

Comment: IDs are used for, well, identification, which fails if you have multiple elements with the same name. They should be unique.

Comment: Ids must be unique within an HTML document. Try using classes instead.

Comment: multiple elements with same id = BAD

Comment: Also, when posting a link to a fiddle you should save first. Otherwise you're just giving us a link to the front page of the website.

Comment: Thanks. I fix the link. Can someone provide an example o how to achieve that using class ? or is it better to create a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find("div").toggle();
});
});
```

Use something similar to this.

Comment: Given the HTML in the question this toggles all divs not just the one below each link. This isn't what the question was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

id are supposed to be **unique**

you should use [**class**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to do this

**[EDIT]** updated the jsfiddle to fit Marko Dumic's solution: http://jsfiddle.net/SugvH/

Comment: Can you rewrite the example using class?

Comment: @soldier1948: you can either create an id for each div (with an index for instance) or use alnorth29 solution, which doesn't change your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divs = [];
    $(".textBox").each(function(index) {
        divs[index] = this;
    });
    $(".clickMe").each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(divs[index]).toggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ID **must** (as per spec) be unique on the page. You can easily rewrite this to use `class` attribute:

```
<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled</div>

<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>

...
```

Initially, you need to either hide `div.textBox` when `DOM` becomes ready, or hide it using CSS.

Then you attach click handlers to `a.clickMe`:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.clickMe').click(function () {
        // find first of following DIV siblings 
        // with class "textBox" and toggle it
        $(this).nextAll('div.textBox:first').toggle();
    });
});
```

However, maybe you don't control the markup but desperately need this done, you can keep your markup as it is and still make it work due to the fact that jQuery uses Sizzle framework to query the DOM which can be forced around the limitation of `document.getElementById()` (which returns only one element).

E.g. suppose you used `id` instead of `class`, if you write `$('#clickMe')`, you'll get the jQuery collection of only one element (jQuery internally used `.getElementById()` to find the element), but if you write `$('#clickMe')`, you get the collection of all elements with the `id` set to "clickMe". This is because jQuery used `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` to find all anchors and then filtered-out the elements  (by iterating and testing every element) whose attribute value is not "clickMe".

In that case (you used your original markup), this code will work:

```
$(function () {
    $('a#clickMe').click(function () {
        $(this).nextAll('div#textBox:first').toggle();
    });
});
```

Again, don't do this unless you absolutely need to!

Comment: nice use of `nextAll` but you probably wouldn't need the tag `a` in this selector: `$('a#clickMe')` (and the `div` too in the second selector).

Comment: @JMax you need those to bypass `getElementById()`. I have it covered.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending an index to each pair of a/div's ids (clickme1 and textbox1, etc). Then when an a is clicked, read the id, take the index off the end, and show/hide the textbox with the same index.