# Issue with $(this) and toggle() multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, toggle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use same div to toggle different parts of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955849/use-same-div-to-toggle-different-parts-of-the-page)

Hello I have the following code:

Javascript/jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).find("a").click(function() {
   $(this).find("div").toggle();
  });
});
```

Html code printed with a for loop:

```
<div>
<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled</div>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
  <br />
  <div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
  <br />
  <div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled 3</div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able:

1. When the page loads I want the  to be hidden and toggle on click.
2. Using the same classes for `<a class="clickMe">` and `<div class="textBox">` to be able to toggle or hide the correct/equivalent `<div>` element.

jsFiddle code:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/A7Sm4/8/
```

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alr3/A7Sm4/9/) will work. Basically changing the first find into just a regular selector, and then going to the parent of the anchor to find the child divs, and toggling them.

One of many ways to accomplish this task though.

Comment: Thanks mate:) Is it possible to start with the div hidden as well?

Comment: you could use the line    '$("a").parent().find("div").hide();'    or just use css, and put display:none on the divs.   Depends on your Use Case as to which approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

:)
    http://jsfiddle.net/A7Sm4/17/

Comment: Like the :) to get it over the minimum character limit! :D

Answer (score 0):

See The Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/fDpT5/)

Jquery Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("a").click(function() {
       $(this).parent().find("div").slideToggle();
     });
   });
```

CSS:

```
.textBox {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
    <br />
    <div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled</div>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
    <br />
    <div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>
</div>

<div>
     <a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
     <br />
     <div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled 3</div>
 </div>
```